Pandas - Attempting to Rearrange Row in Dataframe, but get Error
I'am trying to rearrange a row in the dataframe for the indexed row "Germany", but i get error " TypeError : 'method' object does not support item assignment  " , code is below,
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


combined_global_fx_currencies = r'x:\xxx\xxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx.xlsx'

global_fx = pd.read_excel(combined_global_fx_currencies)


global_fx['Country'] = ['United States', 'China', 'Euro Zone', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Canada', 'Switzerlanter']

global_fx = global_fx.set_index('Country')

## Multiplying by 100, cause by default in pandas its not putting in Percetange Terms like it is on the Excel Filed

global_fx['3 Years']= global_fx['3 Years'] * 100
global_fx['1 Year']= global_fx['1 Year'] * 100
global_fx['YTD']= global_fx['YTD'] * 100
global_fx['1 Month']= global_fx['1 Month'] * 100
global_fx['1 Week']= global_fx['1 Week'] * 100 
global_fx['Daily']= global_fx['Daily'] * 100

## Add Row for Germany and equated to same values for the Euro Zone which is the Eur/USD

global_fx.loc['Germany'] = global_fx.loc['Euro Zone']
global_fx = global_fx.reset_index

global_fx['Country'] = ['United States', 'China', 'Euro Zone', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Canada', 'Switzerland']

global_fx = global_fx.set_index('Country')

print(global_fx)


Error :  global_fx['Country'] = ['United States', 'China', 'Euro Zone', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Canada', 'Switzerland'] TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment


global_fx = global_fx.reset_index -> global_fx = global_fx.reset_index()

It is difficult to provide an answer without an [mre] and if the problematic part of the code is not isolated. Creating an MRE to check the code is necessary for the question, and it is also the best way to help you solve the problem yourself.

@PandaKim , thankyou for that insight, i will consider editing for highlighting the points you just mentioned.  Great, your solution of .reset_index() now adjusted the row "Germany" to the 4th row. But it seems like the Row "Germany" is taking values of row "Japan", since i replaced "Germany" with the row  of "Japan", which "Japan" was previously the 4th row. the row "Germany" should have the same values as the row "Euro Zone", since you can see in the code above i equated the row "Germany" to the same values of "Euro Zone". But it is not doing that, it is giving me the values of "Japan".

How do i correct that ?

Please read the announcement and provide [mre] to get answer. Think of it this way: no sample, no answer.

I just added the complete code for this, the only thing that was missing was the was the file part and the pd.read_excel part that is at the beginning part of the code. Look above

Why are you not providing [mre]? It is required to receive an answer. This is my third time asking. If you do not provide [mre], I will not answer, so I hope this is the last waste of time for both of us.

I provided everything, the only thing i can think of is the two lines of code where i load the pandas and numpy libraries. i have added that now, it is at the very top. This all of the code, everything is there.

Please read the announcement and provide an [mre].  Reproducible example means that we should be able to reproduce your problem. In other words, we should be able to run your code (by copy and paest) and get the same results. If you do not provide a [mre], hard to get answer.

Dude, of course i read it. Everything is there. I think you understand the issue, the question im asking is very basic, simply the values of the row Germany are showing of Japan values, when the Germany values should show the same values as the row of "Euro Zone".

Providing the entire code without [mre] does not mean providing everything. We need a reproducible example. If you think your question is too basic and you don't want to respond to the request, then as a basic question, please try to find the answer through a search by yourself! Good luck!

I responded to the request. the question im asking is basic, you understand the point what im asking, atleast i assume so. now the code for the solution is just a little bit more tedious. But you are ignoring of what im pointing too, and being ignorant of the matter.

Please read the announcement to understand what [mre] is. You did not respond to the request to provide an MRE. When we copied and pasted your code, we got a FileNotFoundError. This means it is not reproducible. Creating a reproducible sample and attaching it to the issue is what is meant by providing an MRE. And what you are misunderstanding is that SO is a place where if you ask a good question, someone will answer it and it will be solved within 15 minutes, even if I don't answer it.

Please read my responses. Your repeating false matters

@Panda Kim , i have answered and found the solution. It was formatting with the reindex method correctly in a more efficient and effective way. Everything as stated was there. Next Time actually take the time and patience to understand what is going on and reading through it thoroughly.

Here is answer below where it rearranged the "Germany" row to the 4th row, and with correct values in the row. The values i wanted for this row was the same values for the "Euro Zone" row. The reindex method is used correctly. The Code is below,
# Rearranging Index and putting index row "Germany" in 3rd Row 
global_fx = global_fx.reindex(['United States', 'China', 'Euro Zone', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Canada', 'Switzerland'])
print(global_fx)

